# Why isn't sunlight polarized?

Tags: polarization

My guess:
[image]
Because polarization happens only when amplitude exists and because the sun is so big that the light rays arriving on earth literally come in all direction, their amplitude is then cancelled out.

.......but this doesn't make any sense, no amplitude means no light at all. No brightness. The earth would then be in darkness.

Comment: The suns rays only come from a small set of directions, I.e. the direction of the sun. Also, "polarization happens only when amplitude exists" does not imply that all light with any amplitude is polarized.

Comment: *"when amplitude exists"* All waves have amplitude all the time. This phrase doesn't make any sense except to distinguish no light (zero amplitude) from light (non zero amplitude).

Comment: The sunlight which does arrive from all directions, the blue sky from Rayleigh scattering, *is* polarized. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_sky_model .

Comment: It is the phases , not the amplitude, that define poloarization. The phases should be coherent

Comment: @annav, yes, so depending how much two light waves are out of phase, the extent to which polarization is cancelled out varies?

Comment: Polarization is getting the light beam to be into phase, by judicious interactions (polarizing filters). One can then split it and have two or more polarized beams etc. A beam is either polarized or not. Two out of phase with each other polarized beams will have a phase difference that will affect their interference patterns, but "extent" does not apply. They have a measurable phase difference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_%28waves%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The light that we receive *directly* from the Sun is emitted in the photosphere, travels in a straight line through the atmosphere to us, and is unpolarised. The photosphere is a region covering the whole surface of the Sun and is also of order hundreds of km thick. Thus the light received at a point on Earth is a pseudo-random mixture from many points on the Sun, each of which was emitted in an independent process. There is little to make these photons coherent in any way, and a random mixture of polarisations at random phases just gives unpolarised light.

That being said, there are regions of the Sun (namely sunspots) that do emit partially polarised light. This is caused by the strong magnetic fields and [Zeeman splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) or broadening of light at wavelengths corresponding to atomic transitions. The split components have their own peculiar circular or plane polarisations This effect is used to estimate the overall magnetic flux from the surfaces of very magnetically active stars or even to map their magnetic fields through a technique called [Zeeman Doppler Imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman%E2%80%93Doppler_imaging).

If your question extends to considering sunlight scattered by the atmosphere - i.e. the sky - then the light *is* [partially polarised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_sky_model). Unpolarised light entering the atmosphere can be considered an equal mix of two perpendicular plane polarisation states. Rayleigh scattering through 90 degrees would select *one* of these polarisation states, causing us to see almost perfectly polarised light from that direction. Smaller scattering angles cause less polarisation, whilst scattering from a variety of heights in the atmosphere means that the polarisation is never perfect.

Comment: FWIW,  the atmosphere causes significant polarization, so at ground level the orientation of your polarizing sunglasses makes a difference.